# c# change modifier when creating event method with +=

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, modifier

If I subscribe a new Method to a Handler and Press "Tab" twice after the "+=" VS will implement a Body like:

```
public class A {
  public A(){
    button1.Click += OnButton1Click();
  }

  private OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  }
}
```

How can I change VS to create the Body of the Method as public instead of private?

Kind regards,
Asat0r

Comment: Why do you want a public event handler? You can create a public method, then call it from your private event handler.

Comment: You really shouldn't make your event handlers public anyway. The only benefit that would give you is to be able to call them from an outside class. Sounds smelly to me.

Comment: Why would you want every event handler to be public in the first place? Is it such a big hassle to just change them afterwards?

Comment: In my case sometimes I need to Unsubscribe the Event. It is based on the Logic we work, that's why I want them to be public. I only need it to call "A.button1.Click -= A.OnButton1Click();"

Comment: unless it is a global event which it isn't in this case it should remain private.

Comment: @Asat0r: That's a slightly odd use case, I'd say. I'd probably encapsulate that as a public method of "UnsubscribeEventHandlers" or something similar. It's unusual for one piece of code to subscribe, but some entirely separate piece of code to unsubscribe. It will work, but it's at least unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change VS to create the Body of the Method as public instead
>   of private?

Not sure if there is any option but why you would like to do that? event handlers are not meant to be `public`. If you want to call the logic inside handler from some other type then refactor that logic to a helper method and re-use that instead probably.

Comment: "event handlers are not meant to be public" - I'm not sure what you mean by that. Whether you use a method to handle an event or not should be pretty much orthogonal to whether you make it public or not. Often they're private, but if the signature of the method is exactly what you'd want to make public, I see no problem in doing so.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I mean, event handlers are non-public always and that make sense cause generally you won't call that handler (like a method) explicitly. Not pretty clear with your comment though

Comment: Yes, usually you wouldn't want to call the method - but presumably if the OP wants to make it public, they *do* want to call that method, or perhaps use it as an event handler from another class. I don't see in what way handlers are "not meant" to be public.

Comment: @DaisyShipton yes they can but that would be weird and have never seen someone to do so since event handlers should be encapsulated within. if some other class wants to use then better bubble that event up to parent container and let it handled there

Comment: Again you're saying that something *should* be the case, but with no justification. I agree it's *normally* the case, but I try not to make any judgements about what a developer *should* do based on either "what normally makes sense" or a vague "should". I've given a couple of more concrete reasons in my own answer, but even then they're reasons that could easily be overridden by other justifications (or deemed not to be a problem in a particular context). Suggestions for particular practices are a lot more compelling with reasons behind them.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have suggested that the method shouldn't be public.

Broadly speaking, I reject that - at least without further justification. *If* you want to expose a method with exactly that signature, I'd normally go ahead and do so. Two caveats around that though:

- Normally the signature of an event handler isn't useful *except* as an event handler; the parameters aren't generally useful when calling the method directly. There are exceptions to that as ever.
- If you subscribe an event handler with a public method, any other code can *unsubscribe* that event handler by creating an equal delegate. If you control all the code in the application, that's not much of a problem.

Both cases can be solved by exposing a public method with exactly the parameters you want (which *could* still be event handler parameters, but often won't be) and then using a lambda expression to subscribe to the event:

```
// I want to be able to call this from other code
public void SaveItem()
{
    // ...
}

// Hook up the event handler using a lambda expression
saveButton.Click += (sender, args) => SaveItem();
```

On the other hand, if neither of the bullet points are an issue, go ahead and make the method public manually. I wouldn't expect there to be a VS shortcut to do so, but simply specifying the `public` modifier is pretty simple.